# A Java class for reading MaCH dosage files v2.0

Tags: java, parsing, io, bioinformatics

Version 2 of [A Java class for reading MaCH dosage files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69980/a-java-class-for-reading-mach-dosage-files)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

/**
 * Created by vu.co.kaiyin.ReadMachDosage on 15/11/14.
 */
public class Dosage {
    final String filename;
    final Pattern splitPattern;

    public Dosage(String filename) throws Exception {
        this.filename = filename;
        splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
    }

    public double[][] readCols(int start, int end) throws IOException {
        try(
                InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
                InputStream gzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileStream);
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzipStream, "US-ASCII");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                ) {
            String line;
            String[] fields;
            ArrayList<double[]> dosageList = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean firstLine = true;
            int nCol;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fields = splitPattern.split(line);
                if(firstLine) {
                    nCol = fields.length - 2;
//          Data indices: x      x    1      2      3
//               Indices: 0      1    2      3      4
//               Columns: 1->241 DOSE 1.1783 0.3498 1.9834 ...
                    if(start < 1) start = 1;
                    if(end > nCol) end = nCol;
                    start++;
                    end += 2; // java end index is exclusive
                    firstLine = false;
                }
                double[] dosage = new double[end - start];
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    dosage[i - start] = Double.parseDouble(fields[i]);
                }
                dosageList.add(dosage);
            }
            double[][] dosageMatrix = new double[dosageList.size()][];
            dosageMatrix = (double[][]) dosageList.toArray(dosageMatrix);
            return dosageMatrix;
        }
    }



    public double[][] readAll() throws Exception {
        return readCols(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Changes:

- Read the file only once
- Removing unused fields
- Bug fixes in array elements assignment
- More specific exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a number of suggestions:

**Exceptions**

I don't think your constructor actually `throws Exception`. Remove it?

**Braces in if-blocks**

Use braces even for one line if-blocks.

```
if(start < 1) {
    start = 1;
}
if(end > nCol)  {
    end = nCol;
}
```

**Start parameter adjustment**

The adjustment of `start` can be done before entering the while-loop. Making the while loop shorter and easier to understand. I suggest placing it at the beginning of the function, as you are adjusting an input parameter. Some people think it is bad practice to overwrite a parameter's value, but that depends on your personal taste. I think it is ok in this case, if done at the beginning of the function.

A different way to handle the situation of an incorrect input would be to throw an exception, because clearly the input is incorrect.

**Documentation**

I'd sugguest adding some comments to at least your public methods, so that the user of your utility function knows how to use it properly. This would also be a good place to document how you handle incorrect input (e.g. the correction of the start value to one, in case the entered value is smaller than 1).

**Pattern as static variable**

As the used pattern for splitting is a constant, you could handle it as such buy using a static attribute like this:

```
private static final Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
```

This saves the jvm from compiling the pattern for each new instance of the `Dosage` class.

**Micro optimization**

You can save yourself the `firstLine` boolean by checking `dosageList.isEmpty()` instead.